# How to invoke a java method

Tags: java

I am very new at java coding. I am having difficulty finding out how to link my `main` method with the method that determines if a value is prime. When I run the code below in eclipse, the method doesn't seem to execute at all. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Also, for the last part I was thinking of having `System.out` print whether the input value is prime or not. ie `true` or `false` would be fine.

```
import java.util.*;

class IsPrime {
    public boolean isprime(int n) {
        Scanner input1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input single integer?");

        int n1 = input1.nextInt();

        int i,c=0;

        for(i=1;i<=n1;i++) {
            if(n1%i==0){
                c++;
            }
        }
        if(c==2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;  
        }
        System.out.println("Your number is:")
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't tell you what you did wrong unless you tell us the symptoms.  Did you get some kind of error message?

Comment: I can see one thing you did wrong, you try to call `System.out.println` after the method has returned.

Comment: You don't have a main method.

Comment: after `if (c==2) return ... else return ... ` the `System.out.println ("Your number is:") ` is never reached.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
   System.out.println("Your number is:")
```

is unreachable as you have an

```
else {
return false;
}
```

before it.

Comment: understood and thanks!, so do i have to create a new method to print out whether the intput integer is prime or not?

Comment: You have to have a main method... see @Alonso Dominguez's answer.

Comment: @user1313137, you have some answers to your question, think about [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of them if it helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what it's said by Strawberry and appclay is right.

In the other hand, your method `isprime` is an instance method whilst your `main` (I guess you talk about the method of your main class) is a class (static) method.

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int possiblePrime = // initialise your parameter
    IsPrime isPrime = new IsPrime();
    boolean primeOrNot = isPrime.isprime(possiblePrime);
    System.out.println("Your number is prime: " + primeOrNot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking to is implement an isprime method and call it in a main.

```
class IsPrime {
    public boolean isPrime(int n) {
        int i,c=0;

        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            if(n%i==0){
                c++;
            }
        }
        if(c==2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;  
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input single integer?");

        int n = input1.nextInt();
        IsPrime isPrime = new IsPrime();
        System.out.println("Your number is prime: " + isPrime.isPrime(n));
    }
}
```

That should do what you want to do. However, there is a bug in your code.
What you have will return true for all numbers not just prime numbers. I'll leave it up to you to spot the bug and the fix.

EDIT: No bug. See below comments.

Comment: The method does work, it's not efficient by any means however. I just coded it (fixing the syntax) and ran it with 5, 13, 10, 25, 91, 97, and 100 and it worked for all of them.

Comment: Sigh! I'm an idiot. I was thinking the loop has to go from 2 to n-1 which would be the case if the if-statement was checking c > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to static and you can reference it without creating an instance of that class

```
public static boolean isprime(int n) {
```